# Where is the info on comeliness?

Tags: adnd-2e, ability-scores

I've been playing AD&D 2e for a while now and our group uses comeliness and luck stats in addition to the standard 6 stats. I know Comeliness was introduced in 1e Unearthed Arcana, but I haven't actually been able to find it in 2e. So far we have just rolled the extra stats how the DM suggested. I would still like to find out where the information is though. Can anybody help me with that? Please, no suggestions for other systems, other methods or netbooks. Just direct quotes from the actual AD&D 2e books and the name of the book where the quote can be found.

Comment: It was actually introduced in the World of Greyhawk campaign setting.  Page 33 of Glossography Book in the Box Set, under Personages & Quasi-Deities it is well detailed.

Answer (score 6):

It was published for AD&D 2nd in Polyhedron magazine issue #89 (November, 1993)

> Comeliness
>
> Much of this scenario relies on the Comeliness rules from the Network’s Living City tournaments. The DM can institute this rule, or the DM can simply substitute Charisma wherever the scenario mentions Comeliness. Here are the Comeliness rules:
>
> Comeliness reflects a character’s physical attractiveness. It can influence the initial reactions NPCs have to a character. Comeliness is not Charisma. The latter score represents a character’s force of personality.
>
> Unlike the original edition of the AD&D game, a character’s Comeliness score is not adjusted based on Charisma, nor can characters with a high Comeliness score “fascinate” others. Comeliness in Living City play affects reaction bonuses that are tied to Charisma. Therefore, a character with a high Charisma and a high Comeliness has a significant reaction bonus.

### \begin{array}{cc}
\text{Comeliness} &  \text{Reaction Adjustment} \\ \hline
    6      &  -2 \\
    7      &  -1 \\
    8-12  &   0 \\
    13      &  +1 \\
    14      &  +2 \\
    15      &  +3 \\
    16      &  +5 \\
    17      &  +6 \\
    18      &  +7 
\end{array}

Credits: I don't have this particular issue of the magazine. The info was extracted from [this post](https://alzrius.wordpress.com/2016/11/20/dd-did-you-knows-comeliness-in-add-2e/) by alzirus.

Answer (score 6):

> ... rules for the Comeliness score in 2E were tucked away in Polyhedron #89 (November, 1993) in an addendum to the adventure “The Ugly Stick.”

Source: https://alzrius.wordpress.com/2016/11/20/dd-did-you-knows-comeliness-in-add-2e/

I cannot find the original magazine but [this](https://www.acaeum.com/awiki/index.php?title=Polyhedron_89) database has an image of the Table of Contents and "The Ugly Stick" is definitely in this.

Fortunately alzarius has copied the Comeliness rules in their post:

> **Comeliness**
>
> Much of this scenario relies on the Comeliness rules from the Network’s Living City tournaments. The DM can institute this rule, or the DM can simply substitute Charisma wherever the scenario mentions Comeliness. Here are the Comeliness rules:
>
> Comeliness reflects a character’s physical attractiveness. It can influence the initial reactions NPCs have to a character. Comeliness is not Charisma. The latter score represents a character’s force of personality.
>
> Unlike the original edition of the AD&D game, a character’s Comeliness score is not adjusted based on Charisma, nor can characters with a high Comeliness score “fascinate” others. Comeliness in Living City play affects reaction bonuses that are tied to Charisma. Therefore, a character with a high Charisma and a high Comeliness has a significant reaction bonus.

\begin{array}{cc}
\text{Comeliness} & \text{Reaction Adjustment}\\ \hline
    6     &    -2 \\
    7     &    -1 \\
    8-12 &    0 \\
    13     &    +1 \\
    14     &    +2 \\
    15     &    +3 \\
    16     &    +5 \\
    17     &    +6 \\
    18     &    +7 \\
\end{array}

Comment: It doesn't include specifics on rolling comeliness though and the chart only goes from 6 to 18.

Comment: @LokiLaufeyson yes, it doesn't and it does. Do you have a point?

Comment: The point is that its only partial information. The chart is one thing. Its the same as Charisma's reaction adjustment chart so it likely follows the same pattern. Something like the details for actually rolling the stat are kind of important though.

Comment: @LokiLaufeyson As I said, I do not have the magazine: I can only supply what I can access. The magazine may have this info.

Comment: @LokiLaufeyson your question was "where can I find it" - you can find it in Polyhedron #89. I believe that answers the question.

Comment: I also requested "Just direct quotes from the actual AD&D 2e books and the name of the book where the quote can be found." clearly requesting both information *and* sources. Only partial information was given as well as a source I have no access to.

Comment: What do you mean you have no access: https://www.ebay.com/sch/sis.html?_itemId=132180612929&_nkw=TSR+Polyhedron+73+Experience+Preferred+Part+2+Bahamut+Tiamat+Mag+EX&_trksid=p2047675.m4096.l9146

Comment: I mean I have no access. They do not have them at the library and I am a broke artist/not-yet-published writer so I can not purchase them. If I had the money I would have already reached the solution of just buying them.